# a HTML tag to search the text in href

Tags: javascript, html

I am try to use the HTML  tag to open the text in href in a new window which search in the default search engine.

```
<a href="Some text" rel="search" target="_blank">Some text</a>
```

When the user clicks Some text, a new tab should open and the browser search "Some text" in the default search engine. Just like we write something in the address bar and the browser searches it in the default search engine.

Is it possible ? if yes, please let me know how to do it.

**UPDATE:**

The problem is I have a list of govt authorities but I do not have the actual URL to redirect my users to their website so what I am trying to do is if the full name of the authority is searched in any search engine the first link will be theirs and user can go to their site.

Comment: do you really need the default search engine. why not use google.com ??

Comment: can do with google as well, but how ?

Comment: just posted an answer please review it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I don't think you can get the default search engine. But if you can use google as the search engine then look at this answer.

If you are going to use html then do it like this

```
https://www.google.com/search?q=<text you want to search>
```

and if you going to go with JS then do it like this

```
window.open("https://www.google.com/search?q="+<text you want to search>,"_blank");
```

[How to launch a google search in a new tab or window from javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16649167/how-to-launch-a-google-search-in-a-new-tab-or-window-from-javascript)

Comment: Thanks, didn't think about it :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are fine with using google, this is the URL format you need to use.
`https://www.google.com/search?q=<your text>`

[Some text](https://www.google.com/search?q=Some+text)

`<a href="https://www.google.com/search?q=Some text" rel="search" target="_blank">Some text</a>`

Answer (score 1):

you can do this with a little JavaScript (I'm using jQuery here):

```
<a href="#" id="searchFrom">some text</a>
$("#searchFrom").click(function(){
  var q=$(this).html();
  window.open("https://www.google.com/search?q="+q,"_blank");
});
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pcht7bus/)

Comment: Thanks I will do it with HTML

Answer (score 0):

The `href` attribute of anchor `<a>` should point to URL.
If the `href` attribute is not present, the `<a>` tag is not a hyperlink.
So the possible values of `href` are:

- An absolute URL - points to another web site (like `href="http://www.example.com"`)
- A relative URL - points to a file within a web site (like `href="index.html"`)
- Link to an element with a specified id within the page (like `href="#top"`)
- Other protocols (like `https://`, `ftp://`, `mailto:`, `file:`, etc..)
- A script (like `href="javascript:alert('Hello');"`)

Comment: Thanks for your answer I know these details that is why was unable to do what I wanted. I have (tried to) explain(ed) what I want to d, it does not necessarily have to be through <a> tag. Is it possible to do what I want using a javascript or something else?

Comment: What do you mean by "search in default search engine"? And why you need to duplicate something, which exists already in every browser?