# Custom search box with google custom search

Tags: html, google-search, google-search-api

I am in the process of adding a search box to my website. My current solution just does a google search of what I put in, however that is the only way I have found that let's me have it look the way I want it aesthetically.

**This is what I have currently**

```
<div id="custom-search-input">
    <form method="get" action="https://www.google.com/search">
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder=" Search" name="q">
        <button class="btn btn-info btn-lg" type="search" style="position:absolute; top:30px; right: 5px;">
            <i class="fas fa-search fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </button>
    </form>
</div>
```

I would like to have so that it looks the way I want but it does a custom google search only in my website.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Oh I see. How could I add my own styling to their custom search bar?

Comment: No, Google doesn't allow to use their search engine like this. You cannot disguise their service and pretend it's your own search engine. But you can display the search results in a new tab (see [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16649308/6171895)) or you could use an `iframe` element to display google website on your webpage (you will not be able to modify it)

Comment: Ok I understand, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can using CSS to rewrite default google custom search-box theme. Just put google custom search javascript into your page and then using css.

https://getsitethemes.com/snippets/custom-google-custom-search-box-new-theme-2535