# Angular 7 get google search result count for list of keywords

Tags: javascript, html, angular7, keyword, google-ads-api

**EDITED**

I have a CSVRecord type as below :

```
  export class CSVRecord {
    public id: any;
    public pubversion: any;
    public guid: any;
    public keywords: any;
    public seometriccount: any;
  }
```

I am trying to read the values from my csv and display it in td, which i am able to achieve from below code.

**app.component.html**

```
<input type="file" #csvReader name="Upload CSV" id="txtFileUpload" (change)="uploadListener($event)" accept=".csv" />
<table class="minimalistBlack" *ngIf="records.length > 0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID </th>
            <th>Pub version </th>
            <th>GUID </th>
            <th>Keywords </th>
            <th>SEO Metric count </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let record of records; let i = index;">
            <td> <span>{{record.id}}</span> </td>
            <td> <span>{{record.pubversion}}</span> </td>
            <td> <span>{{record.guid}}</span> </td>
            <td> <span>{{ record.keywords }}</span> </td>
            <td> <span>{{ record.seometriccount }}</span> </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { CSVRecord } from './CSVModel';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Angular7-readCSV';

  public records: any[] = [];
  @ViewChild('csvReader') csvReader: any;

  uploadListener($event: any): void {

    let text = [];
    let files = $event.srcElement.files;

    if (this.isValidCSVFile(files[0])) {

      let input = $event.target;
      let reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsText(input.files[0]);

      reader.onload = () => {
        let csvData = reader.result;
        console.log(csvData);
        let csvRecordsArray = (<string>csvData).split(/\r\n|\n/);

        let headersRow = this.getHeaderArray(csvRecordsArray);

        this.records = this.getDataRecordsArrayFromCSVFile(csvRecordsArray, headersRow.length);
      };

      reader.onerror = function () {
        console.log('error is occured while reading file!');
      };

    } else {
      alert("Please import valid .csv file.");
      this.fileReset();
    }
  }

  getDataRecordsArrayFromCSVFile(csvRecordsArray: any, headerLength: any) {
    let csvArr = [];

    for (let i = 1; i < csvRecordsArray.length; i++) {
      let curruntRecord = (<string>csvRecordsArray[i]).split(',');
      if (curruntRecord.length == headerLength) {
        let csvRecord: CSVRecord = new CSVRecord();
        csvRecord.id = curruntRecord[0].trim();
        csvRecord.pubversion = curruntRecord[1].trim();
        csvRecord.guid = curruntRecord[2].trim();
        csvRecord.keywords = curruntRecord[3].trim();
        csvRecord.seometriccount = curruntRecord[4];
        csvArr.push(csvRecord);

      }
    }
    return csvArr;
  }

  isValidCSVFile(file: any) {
    return file.name.endsWith(".csv");
  }

  getHeaderArray(csvRecordsArr: any) {
    let headers = (<string>csvRecordsArr[0]).split(',');
    let headerArray = [];
    for (let j = 0; j < headers.length; j++) {
      headerArray.push(headers[j]);
    }
    return headerArray;
  }

  fileReset() {
    this.csvReader.nativeElement.value = "";
    this.records = [];
  }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Now, i need to show the google search result count in the last column of my output, using the keywords (from my previous column).

for Eg: If my `Keywords` column contain keywords like - Amazon, Firestick, bla bla.. then my script should search google for these keywords and show the count of results from page 1.

Say in page 1, it has 5 results, it should display 5.

1) How do i achieve this? - can this be done using Angular?

2) Please explain with code, as i m new to angular 7

Comment: shouldn't it be `record.keywords` ?

Comment: yes tried with `record.keywords` too. but nothing is showing

Comment: so `keywords` value is an array `['abc','qwe','rew']` ? for each record

Comment: Yes ideally... These values are coming from the excel row. So if I provide 10 comma separated values In excel,the same needs to be displayed in my td

Comment: well if they come as an array so you have `record[1].keywords: ['abc','qwe','rew'], record[2].keywords: ['xxx','yyy','zzz']` and so on, the `join(',')` should work. Please investigate a little bit and see what type is the `keywords` value. Also, don't use `any` type for everything. Try to define your types. Else you are using typescript for nothing

Comment: the keyword is a string..i have updated one of my console log - which is how my data should appear inside the table. But in the table, the data for keywords doesn't appear

Comment: I have updated the question with complete code @MihaiT. Could you please check now

Answer (score 4):

first of all what you are trying to achieve, is not user friendly at all.
just to remember, angular will try to bind your cell every time you change something in in your model or UI, (i'm not sure but sometimes even when you scroll the page, it tries to repaint the UI, so you need to cache result , other wise you will make constant request to google, which might cause your client IP address get captcha and no result comes back at you)

so trying to minimize the impact:

in html:

```
  <td> <span>{{ GetResultFromGoogle(record) }}</span> </td>
```

in Ts:

```
    public GetResultFromGoogle(record:CSVRecord ):number {

    if(!record.seometriccount)
    {
    // search google for result and get what you want, answering to this part, is for another quesiton
        this.httpClient.get(googleUrl, neededParamsForSearch).subscribe( data=>{
        //extract result by Xpath  and set to your record
         return record.seometriccount = resultCount;
        });

    }
    else
        return record.seometriccount;

    }
```

Comment: what is googleUrl and neededParamsForSearch? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: sorry bro, but you have to try harder: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16649167/how-to-launch-a-google-search-in-a-new-tab-or-window-from-javascript